# Run rspec test suite multiple times with different parameters

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a suite of specs to run. I would like to run the specs multiple times with different parameters each time. For example, I am testing the SQL scripts against two different database versions. The test cases are the same, but the connection string is different. How will I achieve this?
I am new to RSpec, I was able to get the whole suite working for one version. Just need to know how to rerun with different parameters?

I looked at `Class:RSpec::Core::Runner`, but it's not very clear to me from the documentation that how this can be leveraged to run multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with [env variables](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-environment-variables-2908194). Let's say that you want to run rspec for two different MySQL databases. You can define your db connection like this:

```rb
db_client = Mysql2::Client.new(database: ENV['DB_NAME'])
```

Now you can run your rspec like this:

```sh
DB_NAME=your_custom_db_name rspec
DB_NAME=other_db_name rspec
```

Comment: Thank you so much Povilas! That solves my problem, I was hoping to learn this in a RSpec way of doing it. So that for a much more complex data driven suites, I can apply it. Do you know a way of data driving the RSpec tests?

Comment: There is no "RSpec way of doing it.". RSpec does not actually know or care about your database (well except the hooks that test for pending migrations in rspec-rails). Most gems use Travis together with ENV vars to test on different ruby versions, databases etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shared_examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) to achieve what you want.

Here's an example:

```
RSpec.describe 'shared_examples' do
  shared_examples 'is palendrome' do |word|
    it 'is equal to itself if reversed' do
      expect(word.reverse).to eq(word)
    end
  end

  context 'with the word racecar' do
    # Runs every example is the shared_examples block and passes
    include_examples 'is palendrome', 'racecar'
  end

  context 'with the word apple' do
    # Runs every example is the shared_examples block but fails
    include_examples 'is palendrome', 'apple'
  end
end
```